# \NewDocumentCommand changes spacing in math mode

Tags: macros, spacing

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\trsp{^\top}
\NewDocumentCommand{\tr}{e{^_}}{{^\top\IfValueT{#1}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
$\mathbf{x}_1^{\top}$ versus $\mathbf{x}_1\trsp$ versus $\mathbf{x}_1\tr$
\end{document}
```

Why does the spacing change between these three versions?

```
$\mathbf{x}_1^{\top}$ versus $\vx_1\trsp$ versus $\mathbf{x}_1\tr$
```

Comment: do not show only a snippet but make a full example that can be used for test.

Comment: ok, I put a MWE.

Comment: you have an additional brace group in the \tr command.

Comment: it doesn't work without it.

Comment: The formatting is still incorrect when using this, 

`\NewDocumentCommand{\tr}e{^_}{^\top\IfValueT{#1}{#1}}`

Comment: @JamesPritts It all looks the same to me: please can you post a screenshot with the _exact_ MWE you've used to produce it

Comment: @JamesPritts: I think Joseph is suggesting `\NewDocumentCommand{\tr}{e{^_}}{^\top\IfValueT{#1}{#1}}` which is different both from what you had in your question and also from what you [have in the comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/688067/newdocumentcommand-changes-spacing-in-math-mode#comment1707131_688067).